# mocha describe 'unexpected string error'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am writing the below test cases using Mocha in node.js. Please find the below code :

> describe('Car', function() {
>
> it('can park?',function()
>
> {
>       const car = new Car();
>       assert.equal(car.park(),'stopped');   }); });

I am running this using following command :

```
npm run test
```

It populates following error :

```
> inbox@1.0.0 test /Users/abc/test/
> mocha

/Users/abc/test/Inbox.test.js:18
describe('Car', function() {
     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Can you please help me, what i am doing wrong here?

Note : package.json is also updated with mocha in scripts field.

Comment: did you try "npm install mocha --save" in terminal

Comment: yes i have installed mocha.

npm list mocha
inbox@1.0.0 /Users/abc
└── mocha@5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I know i am answering to my own question but its more like recording it for others.

Just Use following statement in your code at top or before **describe** statements

> "use strict";

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue. How do I resolve this?